# The difference of "edge coloring" and "k-edge coloring.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, coloring

What is the difference between edge coloring and k-edge coloring?

Base from my understanding, edge coloring is just an assignment of colors to edges of graph, such that two adjacent edges have different color. For k-edge coloring, it is also same as the edge coloring but with parameter k.

Does my understanding of the two correct?

Comment: You are correct, typically, we make this distinction because the $k$-edge coloring problem is a decision problem (you answer true if it is possible to color with $k$ colors, and false otherwise), and the edge coloring problem is an optimization problem (you answer what is the minimum number of color necessary to have a proper edge coloring). The decision problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete, while the other not (It is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard). The $k$-edge coloring problem is called the decision version of the edge coloring problem.